# Option sets in crm 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, customization

In my account entity I have an option set (which is local). Now,In my custom entity form I need to add the same option set (need to make it global). Now is there any way where I can link the new option set to the account entity option?. At the end I need both the option sets to be global.

Answer (score 1):

You need to convert your local optionset to be a global optionset, there isn't another solution.

You can check also this tool: https://xrmoptionsetconverter.codeplex.com/ (the author is [Daryl](https://stackoverflow.com/users/227436/daryl), a stackoverflow user)

Is a plugin for XrmToolbox: https://xrmtoolbox.codeplex.com/

Comment: The tool will convert the local option set to a global and it will keep the data as well, as long as the int values are the same between the local version and global (it can even add the global prefix value if it needs to as well ie 1 becomes 100000001).  Be aware that you'll have to run it in each environment as well since it is a breaking change in the normal solution migration process.